# Awesomium click by tag C#

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, awesomium

```
<a class="button" style="letter-spacing: -1px" href="/home" data-executing="0">Go Home</a>
```

I am trying to get Awesomium to click a certain button, Take the example above there is no ID only a tag

```
<a - and attribute being Go Home
```

I have been reading on how to do this and they say to use this:

```
web.ExecuteJavascript(@"$('a').trigger('click');");
```

This doesn't work for me, it doesn't produce the click. It could be because my test site has many tags using

```
<a
```

Is there a way to click this button by using the attribute of "a" being "Go Home" in Awesomium? I have also tried this and it also did not work:

```
        private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (web.IsDocumentReady)
        {

            dynamic document = web.ExecuteJavascriptWithResult("document");
            dynamic submit = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
            submit.Invoke("click");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried `document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].click();`? Of course, if you need first `<a>` click...

Comment: That works fine for the default browser, but it doesn't work for awesomium because awesomium doesn't contain a definition for document. I have already tried that.

Comment: Also if you were referring to  `web.ExecuteJavascript("document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].click()");`That doesn't work either. It shows no errors but still does nothing.

Comment: Well, you can click by moving mouse to this link rectangle on screen and trigger left mouse click. I have this in one of my projects (which is written in C# and uses Awesomium). So you will need `.getBoundingClientRect()` method of DOM element, `public static extern void mouse_event(UInt32 dwFlags, Int32 dx, Int32 dy, Int32 cButtons, IntPtr dwExtraInfo);` and `public static extern bool GetCursorPos(out Point lpPoint);`, both from _user32.dll_ (`[DllImport("user32.dll")]`). It's difficult method (I actually really needed to do it this way), but maybe you have to do it the same way.

Comment: Since Awesomium is based on Chromium (for all that I remember), I suggest to google for all ways to trigger click via JS, not using C# (for example, `link.fireEvent("onclick");`). And, by the way, `document` element exists, that's for sure.

Answer (score 2):

If this element is not a `<button>` it probably doesn't have the `click()` method.

You can try this to check it:

```
JSObject btn = web.ExecuteJavascriptWithResult("document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0]");
if (btn.HasMethod("click"))
    btn.Invoke("click");
else
    // no such method
```

or using dynamic (will throw exception if the method doesn't exist):

```
dynamic btn = (JSObject) web.ExecuteJavascriptWithResult("document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0]");
btn.click();
```

You can use this for clicking such elements:

```
public void JsFireEvent(string getElementQuery, string eventName)
{
    web.ExecuteJavascript(@"
                        function fireEvent(element,event) {
                            var evt = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
                            evt.initEvent(event, true, false ); // event type,bubbling,cancelable
                            element.dispatchEvent(evt);                                 
                        }
                        " + String.Format("fireEvent({0}, '{1}');", getElementQuery, eventName));
}
```

Examples:

```
JsFireEvent("document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0]", "click");

JsFireEvent("document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0]", "mouseup");
```

Also you may find these two simple helper classes useful: https://gist.github.com/AlexP11223/8286153

The first one is [extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) for WebView/WebControl and the second one has some static methods to generate JS code for retrieving elements (JSObject) by XPath + getting coordinates of JSObject)